# creating the code behind file

Tags: asp.net

First i created the TimeSheet.aspx file,then added code files names TimeSheet.aspx.cs file.
created a TimeSheet class and code some code in that ,later in the @page directive added the codebehind attibute with value "TimeSheet.aspx.cs" and inherits attribute with value TimeSheet.

Now i want to make this code behind file to show up as a sub-branch of TimeSheetp.aspx.Just like a designer file.

Like

- TimeSheet.aspx
  |----TimeSheet.aspx.cs

how will i do that.please help me

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Is your project a webforms project? Are you sure you're not using MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of the Solution Explorer, toggle `Nest Related Files`.

Comment: thanks,
not only we have to toggle next related files icon, we have to name the file as TimeSheet.aspx.cs only then code file will become a nest related files.

Comment: I think the Nest Related Files setting is on by default. Also, when you create a new page in VS, you can check "Place code in a separate file" to automatically create the codebehind file and related page attribute.

Comment: you are right when u check mark the "Place code in a separate file" then it will be create, what if i don't do that at the time of creating the web page, and want to add the code behind later.I have to do the step mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not let VS create the file for you when you first make the file, you just need to create a new file (class file, '.vb' or '.cs' extension) in the same directory as the file you wish to add the code behind file to with that file name as the first part of the new file name. Example, default.aspx's code behind file that you create manually will be called "default.aspx.cs".  Then in your original file, make sure you add a page directive for the newly created file: <% @Page Language="VB" Explicit="True" **Codebehind="default.aspx.vb"** %>

Answer (score 0):

The Page directive should be configured automatically and the code-behind created when you create your page in VS.

Comment: Yes. But you might not have created it yourself. It might be an existing file that you want to include in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web forms, you shouldn't have to create the .cs file; it should create it for you.  Right click the aspx and do view code to see the code file.  if you are in an MVC project, there isn't any code-behind, but a controller file.  And so creating the cs file doesn't do anything.